# Denwer лег

Tags: http-status-code-404, denwer, localhost, сервер

После устанавки WebMatrix, не могу зайти на localhost, пишет, что не может найти страницу Error 404. В файле hosts localhost прописан 127.0.0.1

WebMatrix удалил уже, Denwer пару раз переустанавливал - не помогло

в чем может быть дела?

Comment: 1) проверить \usr\local\apache\conf\vhosts.conf , \usr\local\apache\conf\httpd.conf
2) не запущен бинарник апач.
3) может быт конфликтует с какой то службой (приложением). На всякий случай проверьте фаервол.
4) Кстати, ОС какая ?

Comment: порт не занят ?

Comment: да, был занят

Comment: а до этого небось скайп работал, который тоже на 80м сидит?
@Vfvtnjd раз человек говорит о Denwer, осмелюсь предположить что Windows :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле httpd.conf изменил порт на 888 и все заработало

```
# Listen $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}
#NameVirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80}
#< VirtualHost $&{ip:-127.0.0.1}:$&{port:-80} >
```